# cocos2d in xcode communicate to a node.js server service via objective-C library called socket.io

Tags: xcode, node.js, cocos2d-iphone, socket.io

I use xcode 4.6.1 cocos2d 2.x, ios sdk 6.1 , iphone 6.1 simulator.

I want to communicate from objective-c to server by node.js with socket.io.

so, I tried objective-c library called socket.io "socket.IO-objc"

https://github.com/pkyeck/socket.IO-objc

i succeeded a example "SocketTesterARC" in socket.IO-objc to communicate with server "node.js with socket.io".

SocketTesterARC :

```
(void) viewDidLoad {
   [super viewDidLoad];
   socketIO = [[SocketIO alloc] initWithDelegate:self];
   [socketIO connectToHost:@"localhost" onPort:8888];
   [socketIO sendEvent:@"join" withData:@"first room"];
   [socketIO sendMessage:@"hihihi"];
}
```

so, i applied "socket.io" library to new cocos2d project.
i copied from example "SocketTesterARC"'s code to new cocos2d project.

but, error and not process!

```
Connecting to socket with URL: http://localhost:8888/socket.io/1/?t=16807
2013-04-06 21:26:35.129 cocos2dSocketioTest[4311:c07] send()
2013-04-06 21:26:35.130 cocos2dSocketioTest[4311:c07] queue >>> 5:::{"args":["first room"],"name":"join"}
2013-04-06 21:26:35.131 cocos2dSocketioTest[4311:c07] send()
2013-04-06 21:26:35.133 cocos2dSocketioTest[4311:c07] queue >>> 3:::hihihi
2013-04-06 21:26:35.154 cocos2dSocketioTest[4311:1b03] ADDRESPONSE - ADDING TO MEMORY ONLY: http://localhost:8888/socket.io/1/?t=16807
2013-04-06 21:26:35.325 cocos2dSocketioTest[4311:c07] didReceiveResponse() 200
```

server error log :

```
info  - handshake authorized brKX0Zfj9Vge80rxJfig
info  - handshake authorized JsDnUP2nPXUJh83UJfih
info  - handshake authorized pqoc5KS5hD2GsXcsJfii
info  - handshake authorized tX3OQfsgbs-pdWFIJfij
```

server code :

```
io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
console.log("connection");
//join event
socket.on('join', function(data) {
    console.log('join : ' + data);
    socket.join(data);
    socket.set('room', data);
});

//meesage event
socket.on( 'message', function(data) {
    console.log('room : ' + data ); 
    socket.get( 'room', function(error, room) {
        io.sockets['in'](room).emit('message', data);
    });
});
});
```

plz Answer

add,successes client log :

```
2013-04-07 13:47:37.417 SocketTesterARC[1274:c07] Connecting to socket with URL: 
http://localhost:8888/socket.io/1/?t=16807
2013-04-07 13:47:37.424 SocketTesterARC[1274:c07] send()
2013-04-07 13:47:37.424 SocketTesterARC[1274:c07] queue >>> 5:::{"args":["first room"],"name":"join"}
2013-04-07 13:47:37.425 SocketTesterARC[1274:c07] send()
2013-04-07 13:47:37.425 SocketTesterARC[1274:c07] queue >>> 3:::hihihi
2013-04-07 13:47:37.430 SocketTesterARC[1274:1b03] ADDRESPONSE - ADDING TO MEMORY ONLY: http://localhost:8888/socket.io/1/?t=16807
2013-04-07 13:47:37.436 SocketTesterARC[1274:c07] didReceiveResponse() 200
2013-04-07 13:47:37.436 SocketTesterARC[1274:c07] connectionDidFinishLoading() nTOwJjgvumKn_kNM0alf:60:60:websocket,htmlfile,xhr-polling,jsonp-polling
2013-04-07 13:47:37.436 SocketTesterARC[1274:c07] sid: nTOwJjgvumKn_kNM0alf
2013-04-07 13:47:37.448 SocketTesterARC[1274:c07] heartbeatTimeout: 67.000000
2013-04-07 13:47:37.449 SocketTesterARC[1274:c07] transports: (
   websocket,
   htmlfile,
  "xhr-polling",
"jsonp-polling")
```

server log :

```
info  - handshake authorized nTOwJjgvumKn_kNM0alf
connection
join : first room
room : hihihi
info  - transport end (socket end)
```

Comment: On stack overflow sites you should explain what you are doing in a clear english sentence, and not just dump out a list of technical words and punctuation (seriously? `<->` is how you say communicate?). I edited your title and the first sentence to show you an example. Secondly if you are this lost on a starter task, I suggest you simply go all the way back to a working sample and work forward from there. Asking other people to debug your first attempt (failed) to replicate their simple demo is too narrow and I will vote to close unless you edit further.

Comment: thanks, I do not live in an English-speaking country.So, don't accustomed English. I edited contents. There are still insufficient explanation?

Comment: what's the error? All seem good at first glance.

Comment: add successes client, server log.
don't occur "connection" event and  "message" event

Comment: process stop in xcode ,
Thread 1 : EXC_BAD_ACCESS(code=1, address=0x30930825)

Comment: i tested on IOS SDK in xcode same code, OK!
but, don't process on cocos2d

Comment: Troubleshooting network client server communications is not a purely code issue. You have to troubleshoot network connectivity issues, configuration issues, firewall issues, and so on, for yourself.

Answer (score 0):

i find,

cocos2d is disabled ARC therefore don't used SRWebSocket.

The way to solve ARC enable is to use.

use arc in cocos2d 
http://www.raywenderlich.com/23854/arc-and-cocos2d-v2-x